# Wordpress - Need help populating a menu with the titles of Custom Posts with a specific Category

Tags: wordpress, menu, custom-post-type

I'm working with Wordpress 3.1.4 - and trying to dynamically populate a menu with Custom Posts with a specific category as you can see [here.](http://www.escalamadrid.com/kalimba2/)

So on the page - I have the main loop - which is listing through all of the toy products. The products are all from a custom post type labelled 'products' - and each product belongs to a different category - soft toys, games etc.

In the sidebar menu, i have written the following code for each category in order to list products within the given category:

```
<ul class="acitem">
<?php query_posts(array ('post_type' => 'products''cat=games')); ?>
<?php $games_query = new WP_Query("category_name=games"); ?>
<?php while ($games_query->have_posts()) : $games_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>      
</ul>
```

For some reason no list items are being generated. Is it possible this is a conflict with the main loop on the page?

Any suggestions or pointers appreciated! -

PS - I'm using the following plugins:

- custom post type ui
- WP page-navi

in case this has any bearing.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code snippet.

```
<ul class="acitem">
<?php $games_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'product','category_name'=>'games','posts_per_page'=>-1)); ?>
<?php while ($games_query->have_posts()) : $games_query->the_post(); ?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>   
</ul>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for your help boxoft - but when i tried this code i got the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW. I eventually got this to work by swapping your second line for the following - <?php $games_query = new WP_Query('post_type=products&category_name=soft-toys'); ?>. The menu is now working like a dream - many thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 1):

I eventually got this to work by swapping the second line of boxofts' code for the following -

```
<?php $games_query = new WP_Query('post_type=products&category_name=soft-toys'); ?>
```